# Why does ncat -exec work with a shell script but not with a perl script?

Tags: perl, sockets, unix

I'm trying to write a little hardware emulator that reads input from a socket and writes the response back.  I want to use ncat for the networking part and Perl for the logic.  But when I run my perl script with ncat it never sends a response.

First of all, this shows how I want to use ncat.  I'm using /bin/cat for demonstration purposes because it's simple.

Start the server `ncat -l 1234 -keep-open --exec "/bin/cat"`

Start the client `ncat 12.34.56.789 1234`

Doing that causes ncat to echo back the commands like I'd expect.  But when I try to write cat in perl and use it instead of /bin/cat.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    print $_;
}
```

and

```
ncat -l 1234 -keep-open --exec "/path/cat.pl"
```

ncat never sends the response back to the client. Even though from the command line it does exactly what /bin/cat does.  Also, when I use the following bash script with ncat instead of /bin/cat, it works like /bin/cat does.  ncat echoes the response back to the client like I'd expect.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do 
read lin
echo "$lin"
done
```

What do I have to do to get my Perl script to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does stopping the buffering (autoflush) of the standard output help? Add the following at the start of your Perl's cat:

```
$| = 1;
```

You may optionally precede this with `select STDOUT;` if your code did anything funky before that, but for your 3 line test script it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved the problem.  I guess I don't know Perl as well as I ought to.